# Assign props to component variable in JSX

Tags: reactjs

Given this render function, how does one assign a property to the top level child...

```
render() {
   return (
      <div>
         {this.props.children}
      </div>
);
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React provides a way to map over children components using [React.Children.map](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren), which you can use to iterate over each child and [clone](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) to pass props down.

```js
const Container = ({ children, ...props }) => (
  <div>
    {React.Children.map(children, child => React.cloneElement(child, props))}
  </div>
);
```

Below is a demo using the code above.

[image: Edit so.answer.54334021]

[image: demo]

If you need to pass props down to multiple levels, then I'd actually recommend [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to expose top level values down to children/grandchildren/grandgrandchildren etc.